# To create a hive history fact from a daily fact

Tags: sql

I have a fact/table which used to run daily and it doesnot store the data of previous day. I want to create a fact on top of this which will store the data of prvious day along with the daily data.

Best Regards,
Santosh

Comment: OK, and what's your question? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: fro examaple;
Current schema is

insert overwrite table score_daliy_fact
listing_id,
product_id,
fact_update_date ,    *this is nothing but current timestamp when fact run*
score

from  base fact.

Problem statment: This fact only store the data for single day whenever it run.
But I want to create a fact on top of this which can store the previous data as well along the current.

Platform is hivesql